# Can't enable the touchscreen Surface lap 3

Tags: touchscreen, surface

I run Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a Microsoft Surface Laptop 3 1867. I can't enable the TouchScreen....Need help ! It's my first time ever on ubuntu...Linux....

Comment: you can try a linux kernel made for Surface devices specifically, see https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Installation-and-Setup